# Как добавить описание метода, доступное к просмотру через IntelliSense?

Tags: c#, intellisense

Как можно написать свой метод и добавить описание? Использовали эту функцию IntelliSense, которая показывает описание методов? [image: скриншот InteliSense показывает сигнатуру метода и его описание]

Comment: Три раза нажмите на слеш над методом. Или `/// <summary>Description</summary>` https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/codedoc